# Calling JavaScript function from Servlet, Defined in JSP page

Tags: java, javascript, jsp, servlets

i have a JavaScript function

```
function ShowDeptPanel()
{

document.getElementById("table1").style.visibility="hidden";
document.getElementById("table2").style.visibility="visible";
}
```

which is defined in JSP page, but i want to call it from Servlet. How can i do this ?

Note: i want to disable 1 table after a certain check in my Servlet Code.

Comment: You can't call javascript function from servlet.

Comment: @HAL9000 are you aware of what you're saying?

Comment: @mohamedrias yes you can, by using `ScriptEngineManager`, but this is not the appropriate use case for it.

Comment: then how to change content of JSP page, for example enabling disabling of content ?

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza, any other alternative for that ??

Comment: There are several ways to achieve this. Do you need it by performing a complete refresh of the page or partial refresh (ajaxified)?

Comment: complete refresh of a page !

Answer (score 2):

Javascript is client-side, so it HAS TO be executed from the web browser. If what you want to do is execute javascript at the page loading, after a specific servlet has been executed, you can do the following :

1. In the servlet, add a variable (like `executeScript`) in the request attributes
2. In the JSP, check this variable's value, and execute the javascript if it's `true`

If you servlet always sends the same page, then just add you javascript function call in the `onload` attribute of your HTML `<body>` tag

Answer (score -1):

In your JSP, use scriptlet to call the servlet function and get the result.

If we consider it to be boolean value, then

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function ShowDeptPanel()
{

document.getElementById("table1").style.visibility="hidden";
document.getElementById("table2").style.visibility="visible";
}

var serverCheck = <% JavaClass classObject = JavaClass.getInstance();
                         classObject.getMethodChecking();%>;

if(serverCheck==="true") {
    ShowDeptPanel();
}
</script>
```

This is one way to hide the table. If you want it to be dynamic, make ajax call to the servlet and make the servlet return you the response which can be processed in javascript  to hide / show the table.

Comment: scriptlet runs only once at rendering time of the JSP. After that, it becomes static in the generated HTML.

Comment: Yes, I just showed him an example. Before the page is rendered, the scriplet will resolve so based on that the table will be shown or not.

Comment: If he wants it to be dynamic, then he can have ajax call to call the servlet and get the value, based on that he can show or hide the table

Comment: Also, this won't generate the expected results you want to show to OP.

Comment: I assumed that the OP wants to hide the table and he doesn't know how to do it. So he thought of calling javascript function from the servlet.  I need to read more about ScriptEngineManager. Anyways thanks for your suggestion:)